# XMLHttpRequest returning status 0 when sending Json object

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a response from the server but i'm getting a null status. Where i'm getting wrong?
I would like to send from an Script to a server within Max4live Patch.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = 'myURL'


log("1");
xhr.open('PUT', url, true, 'myUser', 'myPass');
log("2");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

log("4");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(JsonExport));
log("5");
log("Status: "+xhr.status+ " "+xhr.statusText);

    if (xhr.status == 4) {
        var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        log("Status");
        log(xhr.responseText);
        log(userInfo);
    } else {
        log("Response");
        log(xhr.responseText);
    }

//log(xhr.responseType["json"]);
delete xhr;
```

i'm getting on the line : log("Status: "+xhr.status+ " "+xhr.statusText) : 
**Status:0 null**... where I would like to get a json object from the server. Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an asynchronous request (see third parameter of `xhr.open()`), and your request is not finished when checking the status.

For async requests you need to implement an `onreadystagechange` handler.

For example take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp